# ArrayAdapter unable to update contents

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to update the contents of my ArrayAdapter. I have tried calling the method `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter and `invalidate()` on the `ListView` but I do not see the data within the adapter being changed. I spent two hours searching through every StackOverflow post about this topic, but none of the answers worked.

Here is the `ArrayAdapter` class which I extended

```
public class ChannelAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ChannelRow> {

Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
ChannelRow[] data;

public ChannelAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ChannelRow[] data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ChannelRowHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new ChannelRowHolder();
        holder.userName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.userNameTextView);
        holder.channelName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.channelNameTextView);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ChannelRowHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    ChannelRow channelRow = data[position];
    holder.userName.setText(channelRow.getUserName());
    holder.channelName.setText(channelRow.getChannelName());

    return row;
}

static class ChannelRowHolder
{
    TextView userName;
    TextView channelName;
}

}
```

Below is my `Activity` which I deal with the adapter.

```
public class ChannelNameActivity extends Activity {

private ListView channelListView ;
private ChannelRow[] channelData;
private ChannelAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_channelname);

    // create ListView of channels
    grabSessions();
    channelData = new ChannelRow[]{ // default data
        new ChannelRow("user1", "channel1"),
        new ChannelRow("user2", "channel2")
    };

    // attach ListView adapters/views
    adapter = new ChannelAdapter(this, R.layout.channel_row, channelData);
    channelListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.channelListView);
    final View contentView = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_channelname, null);
    channelListView.addHeaderView(contentView);
    channelListView.setAdapter(adapter);

....
}

private void grabSessions() {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Session");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                createSessionsList((ArrayList<ParseObject>) objects);
            } else {
                // error with query
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Called from grabSessions()
 * Initializes channelData with the queried ParseObject Sessions
 * @param objects the queried Sessions
 */
private void createSessionsList(ArrayList<ParseObject> objects){
    ArrayList<ChannelRow> channels = new ArrayList<>();
    ChannelRow newRow = null;

    for (ParseObject o : objects){
        newRow = new ChannelRow((String)o.get("hostName"), (String)o.get("chatTitle"));
        channels.add(newRow);
    }

    channelData = channels.toArray(new ChannelRow[channels.size()]);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    channelListView.invalidate();
}

}
```

Comment: See nothing wrong in your code. But three points: are you sure that your data actually changed ? Second, the `invalidate` on the listView is purely useless and could even be worse (I don't think that it's your problem but I'll remove it). Third, try to invoke `notifyDataSetInvalidated()` instead of `notifydataSetChanged`. I'll have a deeper look.

Comment: @LaurentMeyer I think your first point hit the problem. I set the debugger to stop on the line of notifyDataSetChanged and inspected the adapter data. Turns out the data inside it was unchanged, which does not make sense because the previous line changed the data in channelData.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sir;

check this out `private ChannelRow[] channelData;`  that's  your instance variable, you instantiate it in your `onCreate()` this way

```
channelData = new ChannelRow[]{ // default data
    new ChannelRow("user1", "channel1"),
    new ChannelRow("user2", "channel2")
}; // channelData is holding is reference to the object being created with the `new` keyword
```

so for example if you add one more object to `channelData` and call your `notifyDataSetChanged()` it will refresh **but** in your `createSessionsList(ArrayList<ParseObject> objects)` method you assign your `channelData` to a new object like this `channelData = channels.toArray(new ChannelRow[channels.size()]);` and this reference is not what the `ListView`'s `Adapter` data is pointing to, so your `notifyDataSetChanged()` does not work because it has not changed. what you have to do is recall the instantiation line, this is the complete code

```
private void createSessionsList(ArrayList<ParseObject> objects){
ArrayList<ChannelRow> channels = new ArrayList<>();
ChannelRow newRow = null;

for (ParseObject o : objects){
    newRow = new ChannelRow((String)o.get("hostName"), (String)o.get("chatTitle"));
    channels.add(newRow);
}

channelData = channels.toArray(new ChannelRow[channels.size()]);
adapter = new ChannelAdapter(this, R.layout.channel_row, channelData);
//edit started here   
// set your Listview to the adapter    
channelListView.setAdapter(adapter); // you set your list to the new adapter
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();// you can remove it if you like
}
```

**EDIT 1**

if you hate the idea of calling this line `adapter = new ChannelAdapter(this, R.layout.channel_row, channelData);` all the time i'd suggest you use `ArrayList` and use the `ArrayList.add(Object o)` function to update your item then you can all `notifyDataSetChanged()` ..

Hope it helps..

Comment: I create a new Adapter object like you stated, but it the default data still shows.

Comment: did you set the adapter to your listview? `channelListView.setAdapter(adapter);` check the my edit i am adding it, to make it fully complete.@clever_trevor