# Two buttons showing when only creating one in XML

Tags: android, xml

I am creating my layout entirely in XML. I wish to show a `ListView` and always have a button at the bottom of the screen like in the default FullScreenActivity. However, the issue is that the button that is at the bottom is also appearing at the top of the screen.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ff000000"
tools:context=".ChannelNameActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/channelListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/black_overlay"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:ignore="UselessParent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dummy_button"
        style="?metaButtonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/dummy_button" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Duplicate button image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Code note from OP's previous question: [ArrayAdapter unable to update contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788421/arrayadapter-unable-to-update-contents))

Because in your `onCreate()` you are adding Activity Layout as Header View to your ListView which is unnecessary (not required).

So Just remove below code lines from `onCreate()`

```
final View contentView = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_channelname, null);
channelListView.addHeaderView(contentView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to use `android:layout_above="@+id/lnlLayout"` attribute in ListView and `android:alignParentBottom="true"` on LinearLayout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ff000000"
tools:context=".ChannelNameActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/channelListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_above="@+id/lnlLayout"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lnlLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/black_overlay"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:ignore="UselessParent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dummy_button"
        style="?metaButtonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/dummy_button" />

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```