# notifiyDataSetChanged() won't update adapter with new fields

Tags: android, listview, notifydatasetchanged

I have a list of items: `List<SomeObject> items` that is mapped to an adapter to show on a ListView. When I set a new field for a specific item in that list and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` then list doesn't update. For example, I want to show a date TextView in a specific row in the ListView by setting

```
item.get(position).showDate(true);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The view doesn't show until I scroll away from that row and back to it (I'm assuming because of recycling).

Doing `list.setAdapter(adapter);` works but the entire view flashes and there shouldn't be a reason to re-set the adapter.

How can I get the list to update without scrolling?

Comment: check this post maybe might help you [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788421/arrayadapter-unable-to-update-contents/28788650#28788650)

Comment: show me you code of how you initialize you `items`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to change the List that is referenced in the adapter. Add something like this to your adapter:

```
 public void updateData(List<SomeObject> dataItems) {
        this.mDataItems = dataItems;            
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

And then:

```
items.get(position).showDate(true);
adapter.updateData(items);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use adapter.getitem(postion) to get SomeObject and refresh it.

```
SomeObject sobj = (SomeObject)adapter.getItem(position);
sobj .showDate(true);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```